# Joomla administrator login error

Tags: joomla, authentication, administrator

I have a Joomla 3.1 installation on a ubuntu server and it was working fine.
Today, I have downloaded a template and placed the zip file on templates folder, unziped by ubuntu terminal and that's all. Since then, when I try to login on Administrator side, it gives this error:

```
An error has occurred.
0 SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `<prefix>_users`
```

I have deleted the zip files considering it was the only change I've made, but nothing happens. I noticed that if I login incorrectly, it gives another error:

```
An error has occurred.
0 Cannot open file for writing log
```

Like it has some problem to write the log file, but hours ago it could. Anyway, knowing this, I changed all folders/files permissions to 777.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To install template you don't extract it into the **templates** folder. You need to install it like you would any other extension. Try that and see if you get the same issue

Comment: Yeah, I notice that after. But just adding a file inside some folder couldn't make this difference I think. But now I can't try that, because this error is blocking me.

Comment: The error is too cryptic to infer anything. Are you sure that you deleted everything? I find it difficult to see how this type of action would do this to your site anyway, unless the template is rogue or the extraction was to the main installation directory.

Comment: I will end this question. Obviously, it didn't have any relation to the template thing. My coworker who administrate the server it self was changing some things. As I didn't know this, the time coincidence about this problem made me think the way I explained. Anyway, thank you for your help.